# Check if there is a match between a string and all of a given set of regular expressions

Tags: regex, perl

I know one can use OR operator on regular expressions:

```
$str = "Here is a strawhat, some cranberry, and a strawberry!";
while($str =~ /(\bstraw\B|\Bberry\b)/g) {
  print "Thanks for the $& !\n";
}
```

Is there a simple and short way other than a while loop to AND them instead of OR, so that the only match is "strawberry"?

In other words, I need to check if there exists a substring in a string that matches all of the given regular expressions.

Comment: so you want to find a single word that includes everything in a list of substrings?

Comment: As an example with your sample text, if you had `raw` `awb` and `rry` as your substrings, you would want to match `strawberry`?

Comment: Not just substrings. I want to check if a string matches all of a given set of regular expressions.

Comment: But you're not asking if the string matches the RE set, you're asking if a single word in the string matches them? At least that's how your question reads to me?

Comment: Sorry for the consfusion. I need to check if there exists a substring in a string that matches all of the given regular expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you can use [lookahead assertions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Look-Around-Assertions) for this:

```
if ($str =~ /^(?=.*?regexp-1)(?=.*?regexp-2)...(?=.*?regexp-n)/s) {
    # $str matches regexp-1, regexp-2, ..., regexp-n.
}
```

There are a couple of assumptions built into this construction:

- All of the subexpressions are well-formed.
- None of the subexpressions use the `.` metacharacter to mean "any character except a newline".  You could turn this behavior back on with `(?-s:...)` as necessary.

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me, but what if I also want backreference to matches?

Comment: You can use capturing groups as you like, but of course the number of the first group in `regexp-2` will be one greater than the number of groups in `regexp-1`, etc.

Comment: This construct would match "strawhat, some cranberry".  To match all of the patterns within one word, you would need something like: `$str =~ /(?=\w*?regexp-1)(?=\w*?regexp-2)...(?=\w*?regexp-n)/`